# How to find the f-related vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields

So lets say you have a vector field $X = (2x+y) \partial x + x \partial y$ and a diffeomorphism $f(x,y) = (x-2y,2x+y)$, then I need to know how to find the f-related vector fields of X, lets say $\overline{X}$. That is, those that meet:

$\overline{X} \circ f = \partial f \circ X \Rightarrow \overline{X} = \partial f \circ X \circ f^{-1}$

Since $f^{-1} = \left(\frac{x+2y}{5},\frac{y-2x}{5}\right)$

$X \circ f^{-1} = \left[2(x \circ f^{-1})+(y \circ f^{-1})\right] \partial (x \circ f^{-1})  + \left[x \circ f^{-1}\right] \partial (y \circ f^{-1}) = \left[2(\frac{x+2y}{5})+(\frac{y-2x}{5})\right] \partial (\frac{x+2y}{5})  + \left[\frac{x+2y}{5}\right] \partial (\frac{y-2x}{5}) = y (\frac{1}{5}\partial x +\frac{2}{5}\partial y) + \left[\frac{x+2y}{5}\right] (-\frac{2}{5}\partial x +\frac{1}{5}\partial y) = \frac{y-2x}{25}\partial x + \frac{12y+x}{25}\partial y$

And since $\partial f = (\partial x -2 \partial y , 2 \partial x +\partial y)$

$\overline{X} = \partial f \circ X \circ f^{-1} = (\partial x -2 \partial y , 2 \partial x +\partial y) \circ \left(\frac{y-2x}{25}\partial x + \frac{12y+x}{25}\partial y\right)$

And the above composition would give a two-component object, which differs from what I was trying to get, a vector field.

Please let me know how to approach this.

Edit1: So I've seen that I had two main mistakes in what I presented above.

- The first mistake is that is not $\partial f$ but $d f$, which corresponds to the jacobian matrix.
- The other mistake was related to $(x \circ f^{-1})$ and $(y \circ f^{-1})$

So the correct way to solve the problem would be:

$\overline{X} \circ f = d f \circ X \Rightarrow \overline{X} = d f \circ X \circ f^{-1}$

Since $f^{-1} = \left(\frac{x+2y}{5},\frac{y-2x}{5}\right)$

$X \circ f^{-1} = \left[2(x \circ f^{-1})+(y \circ f^{-1})\right] \partial x  + \left[x \circ f^{-1}\right] \partial y = \left[2(\frac{x+2y}{5})+(\frac{y-2x}{5})\right] \partial x  + \left[\frac{x+2y}{5}\right] \partial y = y \partial x  + \frac{x+2y}{5}\partial y $

And the above result can be seen as the column vector $\begin{pmatrix}y \\ \frac{x+2y}{5} \end{pmatrix}$

And since $d f =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -2\\2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$\overline{X} = d f \circ X \circ f^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -2\\2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y \\ \frac{x+2y}{5} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{y-2x}{5} \\ \frac{x+12y}{5} \end{pmatrix} = \frac{y-2x}{5}\partial x  + \frac{x+12y}{5} \partial y$

Comment: I think I answered your question if my calculation is correct. Please let me know by comment if there is anything unclear.

Comment: I would ask that you make a few typographical changes so that what you're doing fits with what all the rest of us write. First, write $\partial_x$ for the vector field $\partial/\partial x$, not $\partial x$. Next, please write $Df$ or $df$ for the derivative mapping, not $\partial f$. Also, you're not indicating where you evaluating the derivative. That can cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the notation of *An Introduction to Manifolds* (second edition) written by Loring W.Tu (in particular, chapter one), so that $$X = (2x+y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

A vector field $\overline{X}$ is $f$-related to $X$ if and only if $f_{*}X=\overline{X}$. More precisely, $f_{*, ~p}(X_p) = \overline{X}_{f(p)}$ for every point $p$ in the domain of $X$. In our case, $\overline{X}_q=f_{*,  ~p}(X_{p})$ where $p=f^{-1}(q)$.

Note that \begin{align} \ f_* = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix} \end{align}

in a sense that $$f_{*} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{p} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} + 2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{q} $$
$$f_{*} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{p} \right) = -2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{q}  $$

Write $$\overline{X}=f(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+g(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}  $$

Put $q=(a,b)$. Then $$\overline{X}_{q}=f(a,b)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} +g(a,b)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg|_{q}$$

On the other hand, $p=f^{-1}(q)=\frac{1}{5}(a+2b, b-2a )$.

Thus \begin{align} X_p &= \left( \frac{ 2a+4b+b-2a}{5} \right)
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{p} + \left( \frac { a+2b }{5} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{p}
 \\ &=b  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{p} + \left( \frac { a+2b }{5} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{p}\end{align}

Finally, \begin{align} f_{*, ~p}(X_p) &=b \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} + 2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{q} \right)+ \left( \frac { a+2b }{5} \right) \left( -2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{q}\right) \\ &=
\left( \frac { -2a+b }{5} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} + \left( \frac { a+12b }{5} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{q}  \end{align}

Therefore, $f(a,b) = \frac{1}{5}(-2a+b) $ and $g(a, b)= \frac{1}{5}(a+12b)$.

In short, $$\overline{X}= \left( \frac { -2x+y }{5} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +\left( \frac { x+12y }{5} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Sorry I am really not sure If your answer is correct since you did it in a different way as I did

Comment: I've read my notes and I've seen that your method is essentially the same. Please check my answer and let me know if you can find why mine (or yours) is wrong

Comment: I've seen that the methods are essentially the same, but for some reason we're using the traspose matrix of the other. IMO, your answer makes more sense, but I just need to know if mine is wrong or not. Please help me clarify this point.

Comment: I corrected the error in my answer, and do calculations accordingly. Here is the relevent part: \begin{align} \ f_* = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix} \end{align} in a sense that  $$f_{*} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{p} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} + 2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{q}$$ $$f_{*} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{p} \right) = -2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{q} +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{q} $$ Your result is correct. @KoalaBoy